# Is it possible to disable expand on certain rows?

Tags: react-admin

I would like to create a `DataGrid` where only component that have a certain property can be expanded. For example:

```
   comments: [
        { id: 0, author: 'a', text: 'no', responses:[2]},
        { id: 1, author: 'b', text: 'yes' },
        { id: 2, author: 'b', text: 'perhaps' }
    ]
```

I would like to display this array, but only first option would be expandable, since it's the only one that has `responses`. Is there a way of achieving that without rewriting the `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no. I would suggest to display an empty state component instead.

**Edit**

Here is an extract from the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#body-element):

By default, `<Datagrid>` renders its body using `<DatagridBody>`, an internal react-admin component. You can pass a custom component as the `body` prop to override that default. Besides, `<DatagridBody>` has a `row` prop set to `<DatagridRow>` by default for the same purpose. `<DatagridRow>` receives the row `record`, the `resource`, and a copy of the `<Datagrid>` children. That means you can create custom datagrid logic without copying several components from the react-admin source.

My suggestion would be to copy the original `<DatagridRow>` component and add an `isExpandable` prop accepting a function which will be called with the row `record` to conditionnaly display the expand button.

You could then use this custom `DatagridRow` like this:

```
import MyDatagridRow from './MyDatagridRow`;
const MyDatagridBody = props => <DatagridBody {...props} row={<MyDatagridRow />} />;
const MyDatagrid = props => <Datagrid {...props} body={<MyDatagridBody />} />;
```

However, as we already have an `isSelectable` prop, I also suggest to open a new feature request issue on react-admin repository to add an `isExpandable` prop.

Comment: That's what I did, but this way you still get the 'expand' button.

Comment: You might want to override the default datagrid row, simply wrapping the original and remove the expand for some records. Let me try that and get back to you